# Shard Existing Collection - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a mongo collection on farm1-server1 and I managed to replicate it to farm2-server1 - the db path is /db/data. farm2-server1 is a part of 3 servers and I want to shard the collection I just replicated between all 3 servers. In order to do that, I stopped replication on server1, started mongod (on port 27017) and pointed it to the collection I replicated (/db/data) - I also added the directive:
configsvr = true.

I started mongos and added the following directive
configdb = server1:27017

Then I started the shard processes (mongod) on each one of the server 1-3 with the directive:
shardsvr = true

I expected the collection to be sharded, but what happens is that the old collection I replicated is not recognized in this configuration, hence it cannot be sharded.

I have read that existing collections can be sharded so I must be doing something wrong here. Any help is appreciated. I can provided configuration files is required.

Thanks, Noam

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have missed some steps - you need to

1. add shards
2. enable sharding
3. shard the collection

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Configuring+Sharding#ConfiguringSharding-ConfiguringtheShardCluster

Comment: Thanks but my problem is that even before trying to shard the collection, when running shard1 as configdb, it doesn't recognize the existing collection that I want to shard.